# Draw on one side of a JPanel

Tags: java, swing, java-2d, custom-painting

I want to program an application that lets you draw circles with a mouse click on the left side of a `JFrame`, and all the points are getting "mirrored" to the right side. The first problem I encountered was that when I try to implement this draw-mechanic in my frame, no circles appear.

```
public class Application{
  int x,y;
  private JPanel container;

  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
        new Application().gui();
      }
    });  
  }

  public void gui()
  {
    int height = 250;
    int width = 700;
    JFrame jframe = new JFrame();
    container = new JPanel();
    container.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    container.add(new DrawCircle(), BorderLayout.WEST);
    container.setVisible(true);
    jframe.add(container);
    //jframe.add(new DrawCircle());

    jframe.setSize(500,700);
    jframe.setVisible(true);
    jframe.setTitle("Title");
    jframe.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    jframe.setResizable(false);

  } 
}
```

It works (on the whole frame) when I use `container.add(new DrawCircle)` but if I want to add constraints, it doesn't.

Here is the circle class:

```
public class DrawCircle extends JPanel implements MouseListener
{
  ArrayList<Point> p = new ArrayList<Point>();

  public DrawCircle()
  {
    addMouseListener(this);
  }

  public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
  {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    for(Point point : p)
    {
      g.fillOval(point.x,point.y,30,30);    
    }  
  }

  @Override
  public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
  }

  @Override
  public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  }

  @Override
  public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  }

  @Override
  public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
    p.add(new Point(e.getY(), e.getX()));
  }

  @Override
  public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
  }

  @Override
  public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
  }

  @Override
  public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent arg0) {
  }
}
```

Comment: A related example is examined [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2244157/230513).

Comment: Why did you delete the `DrawCircle` code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's go through your problems:

> The first problem I encountered was that when I try to implement this draw-mechanic in my frame, no circles appear.

This is because you forgot to call [`JPanel#revalidate()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#revalidate()) and [`JPanel#repaint()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#repaint()) whenever you click somewhere in the `DrawCircle` class.

So, you could change your `mousePressed()` method to:

```
@Override
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
    p.add(new Point(e.getX(), e.getY()));
    revalidate();
    repaint();
}
```

Note that I also changed the `e.getX()` and `e.getY()` calls, because they were on the wrong places (unless you want them that way).

That will make your circles to appear, but, your `DrawCircle` is really thin (I changed the height of your `JFrame` to 200 for this image, otherwise it would be really tall):

[image]

The red part is your `DrawCircle` panel.

To fix this you need to override its `getPreferredSize()` method:

```
@Override
public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
    return new Dimension(width, height);
}
```

That will make your `JPanel` to return half the size, `width` and `height` were passed as parameters to the constructor, and your class `DrawCircle` should now look like this:

```
class DrawCircle extends JPanel implements MouseListener {
    ArrayList<Point> p = new ArrayList<Point>();
    
    int width = 0;
    int height = 0;
    
    public DrawCircle(int width, int height) {
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
        addMouseListener(this);
    }
    
    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(width, height);
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        for (Point point : p) {
            g.fillOval(point.x, point.y, 30, 30);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        p.add(new Point(e.getX(), e.getY()));
        revalidate();
        repaint();
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
    }
}
```

And the output would be something like this:

[image]

> It works (on the whole frame) when I use container.add(new DrawCircle)

That's because by default `BorderLayout` places by default the elements on the `CENTER` region, and if you have nothing else in the rest of orientations (`NORTH`, `SOUTH`, etc) it will take the whole space.

Now let's continue with how to solve your problem:

I also made some changes to the `Application` class (which in my case I renamed to `CustomPaintingInHalfFrame`):

These changes were:

- Create final constants for the `WIDTH` and `HEIGHT` attributes.
- Removal of unnecessary `JPanel` with `BorderLayout` layout, as `JFrame` already has this layout by default, I simply added our `DrawClass` to it.
- Drawing of a border for the `DrawCircle` panel (as you don't want a division between both (left and right) parts of your `JFrame` as stated in your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41685700/two-jpanels-in-one-jframe) you can simply remove it (I recommend you to leave it there while you're testing so you know where left panel ends and right panel starts.
- Passing `WIDTH / 2` and `HEIGHT` as parameters for `DrawCircle` constructor, so it can return the correct `Dimension`.

So, our class should now look like this:

```
public class CustomPaintingInHalfFrame {
    int x, y;
    public static final int WIDTH = 500;
    public static final int HEIGHT = 200;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new CustomPaintingInHalfFrame().gui();
            }
        });
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("serial")
    public void gui() {
        JFrame jframe = new JFrame("Title");
        
        DrawCircle dc = new DrawCircle(WIDTH / 2, HEIGHT);
        
        dc.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.RED));
        
        jframe.add(dc, BorderLayout.WEST);
        
        jframe.setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
        jframe.setVisible(true);
        jframe.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        jframe.setResizable(false);

    }
}
```

---

## Additional Tips

1. I recommend you to rename your `DrawCircle` to `Circle` or something like that. As a [convention](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html), *Classes* names should be *nouns*
2. Rename `gui()` method to `createGui()` for example because, as Classes names, *method* names should be *verbs*